# parameratized SQL queries for queries to s3 buckets

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, sql-injection

I have a CSV file in an s3 bucket and I'm accessing it using the boto3 library. I'm using the `select_object_content` function to query the file with SQL language.

This is my code:

```
resp = self.s3_client.select_object_content(
    Bucket=S3_BUCKET_MAPPING,
    Key=S3_BUCKET_MAPPING_KEY,
    ExpressionType="SQL",
    Expression=f"SELECT * from s3object s where s.field = 'value'",
    InputSerialization={
        "CSV": {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"},
        "CompressionType": "GZIP",
    },
    OutputSerialization={"JSON": {}},
)
```

My questions are about the expression: `f"SELECT * from s3object s where s.field = 'value'"`

1. Is SQL injection a concern for this type of data fetch when the data store is in S3 and not actually a SQL database?
2. If SQL injection is a concern, is there a way to parameratize this expression the way you would if you were writing code that accesses a SQL database? I haven't been able to find anything so far to help.

Answer (score 0):

s3 supports a [limited SQL syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html).  As long as you are using static SQL or are using the parameter passing s3 should correctly handle parameters.

You could, of course, get in trouble if you start creating SQL expressions from untrusted strings.  But that doesn't seem to be the case here.